# GeoTools and GDAL: CRS WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, java, geotools, well-known-text

I would like to achieve the same output as for GDAL using the GeoTools library:

```
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:32632");
    String wkt = crs.toWKT();
    System.out.println(wkt);
```

GeoTools output:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 9.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
```

GDAL output:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
```

There are some minor differences, including missing authority in some cases, indents, etc. For example,

GDAL:

```
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
```

GeoTools:

```
  UNIT["m", 1.0],
```

Is is possible to tune GeoTools such that it outputs the same WKT as GDAL?

What are the other ways to print the same WKT output to GDAL but *not* using native GDAL libraries?

Comment: which GeoTools referencing module are you using?

Comment: Also, does it really matter? They are functionally identical, that is all the numbers are the same

Comment: Yes, this is important to me. I use GeoToools v18.0: gt-main, gt-epsg-hsql, gt-api from Maven

Answer (score 1):

I'm still no clear as to why the formatting of the WKT matters to you, but if you switch to the [`gt-epsg-wkt` module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/wkt.html) you can edit the raw definition of your projection to match your requirements.

The indentation is a simple search and replace.

Comment: Will you kindly share any usage examples?

Comment: examples of what?

Comment: `gt-epsg-wkt` module. Is that just a list of WKT output for EPSG codes?